# wpml accor undefined wpml_getLanguage() on page template

Tags: wpml

I am using wordpress wpml plugin to display selected language content.

```
if(wpml_getLanguage()=='en'):
    echo esc_attr($avocation_options['home-post-title-1']); 
endif;
if(wpml_getLanguage()=='sv'):
    echo esc_attr($avocation_options['home-post-title-swedish1']); 
endif;
```

Comment: i am facing this type of error:  `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wpml_getLanguage() in /home/hidn/public_html`

Answer (score 0):

I got solution of this problem

`if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en') {
                                    echo wpautop($avocation_options['home-post-desc-1']);
                            }
                            if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'sv') {
                                   echo wpautop($avocation_options['home-post-desc-swedish1']);
                            }`